# Is there any way to use web sockets on react-native without installing extra dependencies?

Tags: javascript, websocket, react-native

I have seen that there is a library which uses socket.io, [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-socketio). I'm getting some errors using it, so I was wondering if there is any way to use websockets without installing extra dependencies on my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the native API, I believe. From Facebook docs:

> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#websocket-support